Proximal point operator of maximum of functions
I want to know whether the proximal point operator of a function with a special structure can be expressed in terms of simpler proximal point operators.
Setup:
For a proper, convex and lower semicontinuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{ + \infty \}$ define the proximal point operator
$ \mathrm{prox}_{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n,\, x \mapsto \mathrm{argmin}_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\lbrace f(y) + \frac{1}{2}\lVert y - x \rVert_2^2\right\rbrace$.
It is known that for some functions like $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ or $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ the poximal point operator can be written down in closed form.
Question:
Given two proper, convex and lower semicontinuous functions $f_1, f_2:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{ + \infty \}$ define $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{ + \infty \},\, x \mapsto \max \left\lbrace f_1(x), f_2(x) \right\rbrace$.
The function $f$ is proper, convex and lower semicontinuous by definition. Is there a way to express $\mathrm{prox}_f$ in a closed form using $\mathrm{prox}_{f_1}$ and $\mathrm{prox}_{f_2}$ without to much computational overhead?
I do not think this is possible or at least I cannot see how this can be done.
